# Using SET command on postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to install the TIGER geocoder in PostGIS, but I have run into a problem. I am using the these [instructions](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder). I need to change the program executables. To get what the program executables currently are, I run the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM tiger.loader_platform WHERE os = 'ravim';
```

Then I run,

```
 SET unzip_command ="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\8z.exe".
```

However, doing so gets me an error message: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "unzip_command". I don't understand why I am getting that error message.

Here is the code used to create the table (The table is automatically generated when the geocoder extension is added)

```
-- Table: tiger.loader_platform

-- DROP TABLE tiger.loader_platform;

CREATE TABLE tiger.loader_platform
(
  os character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  declare_sect text,
  pgbin text,
  wget text,
  unzip_command text,
  psql text,
  path_sep text,
  loader text,
  environ_set_command text,
  county_process_command text,
  CONSTRAINT loader_platform_pkey PRIMARY KEY (os)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tiger.loader_platform
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE tiger.loader_platform TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE tiger.loader_platform TO public;
```

Thanks Falmarri!, that looks like it solves the problem.

Comment: Where does `set unzip_command` exist in those intructions? What are you trying to do exactly. You should be able to unzip any files outside of Postgres itself.

Comment: I am going to have to download a massive amount (15 gb) of spatial data and these commands are supposed to automate the process. The remained of the command should look something like this (this isn't my data)

Comment: Why are you trying to use double quotes for a string in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the wrong thing. The SET command that you're running is for setting configuration. You want to update your table;

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html